# How to echo based on user permissions

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to build an access level system where admins see x, supervisors see y and users see z (not actual roles).

Not built an access level system before but have thought about using something like the below but it doesn't work:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Usertype'])){

  if($_SESSION['Usertype'] == "admin"){
   echo "You are an admin";
   }
   else {
     echo "You are not an admin";
   }
}
```

or even this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Usertype'])){

  if($_SESSION['Usertype'] == "admin"){
   echo "You are an admin";
   }
  if($_SESSION['Usertype'] == "supervisor"){
   echo "You are a supervisor";
   }
  if($_SESSION['Usertype'] == "user"){
   echo "You are a user";
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there are any error or anything? Because this should work without problem. If you use a database, just add user type to session on login. or directly check if they are admin (or user etc) from database.

Comment: have you put session_start() on the top of the page? Check print_r($_SESSION) to see if UserType is set.

Comment: I have a session started and the login system is functional it is just a case of trying to get the system to read the field from the database which doesn't seem to be working. This is currently set:

```$_SESSION['Usertype'] = $row['Usertype'];```

There are no errors

Comment: @Antonio try a var_dump() on your row['Usertype']; Maybe it is empty?

Comment: I have done a print_r($_SESSION) and it is not displayed and yet it is set within my login.inc.php file that processes the login request

Comment: Could you add the code that fetches the user information from your database?

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['Usertype'] = 'admin';
echo $_SESSION['Usertype'];
if(isset($_SESSION['Usertype'])){
  if($_SESSION['Usertype'] == "admin"){
   echo "You are an admin";
  }
  if($_SESSION['Usertype'] == "supervisor"){
   echo "You are a supervisor";
  }
  if($_SESSION['Usertype'] == "user"){
   echo "You are a user";
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi llia,

What are you using to set the session variable? I think this is where I am going wrong

Comment: session_start();               $_SESSION[“admin”] = “admin”;